# find repeated values in an array and print them to list view in android

Tags: android, arraylist

I am new in android and I am trying to get the duplicate values in an array list. I have searched over the internet but I got nothing.

My project has two array lists one is for numbers and the second one is for displaying them. And if the first array list contains a duplicate values, the second one will display all the values and the duplicate ones will be displayed with a stars to mark them as a duplicate values.
So I have tried the following code but I have got nothing. In this situation, array list contains [9,9,5,7].
The problem is I do not get what I need, here is my code.
Note that: arrayList object that contains the numbers, array object will display them.. So any help on this?

```
arrayList.add(Integer.valueOf(students.getSeatnum()));
array.add(students.getStuden_name() + ", Student " + students.getStudent_id() + ", Seat Num: " + students.getSeatnum());

Set<Integer> seenValues = new HashSet();

for(Integer value: arrayList) {
    if(seenValues.contains(value)) {
        array.add(students.getStuden_name() + ", Student " + students. getStudent_id() + ", Seat Num: " + students.getSeatnum()+ "****");
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(StudentInfo.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else {
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(StudentInfo.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an Adapter which accepts arrayList you have created.
Assuming you are using ListView from your variable name convention.

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final List<String> values;

    public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, List<String> values) {
        super(context, -1, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context. getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        textView.setText(values.get(position));

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Your method will look like this

```
ArrayList<String> array =  new ArrayList<>();
    Map<Integer,Integer> seenValues = new HashMap<>();
    int i=0;
    for(int value : arrayList){
        if(seenValues.containsKey(value)){
            if(seenValues.get(value) !=-1){
                array.set(seenValues.get(value), String.valueOf(value) + "*");
                seenValues.put(value,-1);
            }
            array.add(String.valueOf(value)+"*");
        }else{
            array.add(String.valueOf(value));
            seenValues.put(value,i);
        }
        i++;
    }

MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new adapter(context,array);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Let me clearly understand what you need..
[9,9,9,7,4,3,3] ----> [9*,7,4,3*]
or
[9,9,9,7,4,3,3] ----> [9*,3*]

Comment: The above code will work @Sawsan. I have edited it for your use case.

Comment: What i need is: [9,9,9,7,4,3,3] ------> [9*,9*,9*,7,4,3*,3*]. So I tried your suggestion but it gives me an error, tried to solve it but no results occur  `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 9, Size: 0` in line `seenValues.add(value, array.size()-1);`

Comment: sorry for so many edits, but this edit will definitely work as per your requirements and it is O(n) solution. @Sawsan

Comment: THANKS ALOT it finally worked with me... I really appreciate your efforts and help in this thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
public class Test {
    List<Integer> digits ;
    List<String>  digitsWatch;
    public Test() {
        digits = Arrays.asList(9,9,9,5,7,3,3);
        digitsWatch = new ArrayList<>(digits.size());

        // copying your array
        for (int i = 0; i < digits.size(); i++) {
            digitsWatch.add(digits.get(i).toString());
        }

        //filtred values
        boolean hasDublicaqtes = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < digits.size() -1 ; i++) {
            for (int j = i +1; j < digits.size() ; j++) {
                if(digitsWatch.get(j).equals(digits.get(i).toString())  ) {
                    hasDublicaqtes = true;
                    String tmp = digitsWatch.get(i) + "*";
                    digitsWatch.set(j,tmp);
                }
            }
            if(hasDublicaqtes) {
                String tmp = digitsWatch.get(i) + "*";
                digitsWatch.set(i,tmp);
            }
            hasDublicaqtes = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe it's not an optimal way but it works!